# Trying to convert some columns of a dataframe from float to int in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to typecast half the columns in my dataframe from float to int.

Here is the code I am using. Name of my data frame is 'genre_top10'. and there are 45 columns. all are in float 64 format. I want to change the first 27 columns to int.

```
genre_top10.iloc[:,0:27] = genre_top10.iloc[:,0:27].astype(int)
genre_top10
```

But even after running the below code I am still getting floats. The cols are not getting converted to int.

Here is the part of the original dataframe.

```
           CVotes10    CVotes09     CVotes08
Action     102144.10    114433.19   150895.32   
Adventure   94596.29    105636.63   138482.32   
Animation   61960.18    72566.09    104837.64
```

Here it is after running my code.

```
            CVotes10    CVotes09    CVotes08    
Action      102144.0    114433.0    150895.0    
Adventure   94596.0     105636.0    138482.0
Animation   61960.0      72566.0    104837.0
```

Comment: tried out ur code and works fine on my end. is it possible that the columns are not completely float? maybe check the dtypes of the columns?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. How is the DF built? There might be a simpler/earlier way to change the dtypes.

Comment: you cannot have a column with ints and floats (Well you can but you have to make the dtype object, which is suboptimal)

Comment: @JoranBeasley - the OP is not trying to mix ints and floats within a column - the slicing is across columns, for all rows.

Comment: Is it possible you introducing empty/NaN values into some of your rows in one of the steps? Or are you doing any math with mixed float and int types? Either of these would convert an integer column to a float. See the pandas docs on [working with missing data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html).

Comment: As @MichaelDelgado says, you might have `NaN` in your data. Try `astype('Int64')` to see if it works for you.

Comment: Works for me too. Are you sure you are checking the correct columns ?